# Listen for firestore changes for a given amount of time?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener, es6-promise

I have a field-value in a Firestore document, "fruit: apple", and a local variable named `myFruit`. I get the document, and set `myFruit` to "apple". Then, I want to listen to this field until it changes to "fruit: pear", or 20 seconds, whichever is shorter. If it becomes "fruit: pear", I was to set `myFruit` to "pear" and move on. Otherwise, I want to change the variable, after 20 seconds, to "apricot". Currently, my promise waits 20 seconds then executed the function. I want it to resolve as soon as fruit changes, no matter what it changes to, or after 20 seconds. Thank you.

```
const documentReference = db.doc("shopping/groceries");
const documentSnapshot = await docRef.get();
const documentData = documentSnapshot.exists ? documentSnapshot.data() : {};
let myFruit = documentData["fruit"];

// Set a listener.
const observer = documentReference.onSnapshot((docSnapshot) => {
    myFruit = docSnapshot.data()["fruit"];
}, (error) => {
    console.log(`Encountered error - observeQuery: ${error}`);
});

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {return myFruit === "pear";}, 20000);
}).then(() => {
    // It was set to pear.
    observer();
}).catch(() => {
    // Set to apricot.
    myFruit = "apricot";
    observer();
});
```

Comment: "*Actually, I kinda know it's wrong*" - your question should explain what exactly is wrong by stating what it does do that's different than what you expect.

Comment: On Stack Overflow "it's doesn't work" usually isn't enough information to work with.  I suggest reading this in order to learn how to ask a complete question with enough information that anyone can use to reproduce the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask